# Android Studio: How to populate a Spinner from database using Retrofit 2, MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, retrofit2

I'm rather new to android app development and I've been reading about the Spinner and the different ways to populate them but none of the references I've read, specify how to populate it from a database.

I have read a few questions that have been asked on here and some tutorials on other websites but none specify how to populate a Spinner from MySQL database using Retrofit 2.

This is how far I've gotten so far.

**RetrofitBuilder**
This is the retrofit builder class

```
package com.testproject.test.network.config;

import com.testproject.test.BuildConfig;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import android.content.Context;

import okhttp3.Cache;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitBuilder {

    public static Retrofit builder(Context context) {
        OkHttpClient.Builder okhttpBuilder = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder();
        okhttpBuilder.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okhttpBuilder.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okhttpBuilder.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
        Cache cache = new Cache(context.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
        okhttpBuilder.cache(cache);

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            okhttpBuilder.addInterceptor(interceptor);
        }

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Config.BASE_URL)
                .client(okhttpBuilder.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**CountryListModel**
This is the model class for the country list

```
package com.testproject.test.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class CountryListModel{

    @SerializedName("country_id")
    private int country_id;
    @SerializedName("country")
    private String country;

    public CountryListModel() {
    }

    public CountryListModel(int country_id, String country) {
        this.country_id = country_id;
        this.country = country;
    }

    public int getCountry_id(){
        return country_id;
    }

    public void setCountry_id(int country_id) {
        this.country_id = country_id;
    }

    public String getCountry(){
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country){
        this.country= country;
    }
}
```

**CountryListInterface**
This is the interface for the country list

```
package com.testproject.test.network.interfaces;

import com.testproject.test.model.CountryListModel;
import com.testproject.test.network.config.Config;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface CountryListInterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @GET(Config.API_COUNTRY_LIST)
    Call<CountryListModel> getCountryList();
}
```

This is what I have so far. Now I'm trying to figure out on how to proceed on the **MainActivity** class. What is it that I need to add to make the spinner work.

I already have a Spinner in place in the main_activity.xml

```
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/register_country"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/register_name" />
```

On and this is the output of the country list array from the database. it's just a sample output.

```
{"country_list":[{"country_id":"1","country":"United States"},{"country_id":"2","country":"Canada"}]}
```

If there is any other piece of code that I need to provide, let me know and I'll gladly provide it if I have it available.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post your activity class too please? I want to see your retrofit request